# OAuth2 - How to allow only users from Google App which has many domains to sign in

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-signin

I have a custom JS web app with Google OAuth2 sign-in. I know I can restrict sign in for a specific domain by the `hosted_domain` param in the `gapi.auth2.init()` method.

But in our Google App we use many domains (`company.com` - primary domain in GoogleApps, `company.co.uk`, ...).

When I set `hosted_domain` to be `company.com` and tried to login with `user@company.co.uk` mail I get rejected with error object from `googleAuth.signIn()`

```
{
     accountDomain: 'company.co.uk',
     expectedDomain: 'company.com',
     reason: 'Account domain does not match hosted_domain specified by gapi.auth2.init.',
     type: 'tokenFailed',
}
```

Is there an option to set multiple hosted domains for sign-in or I have to implement a custom validator?